# CURL Unable to find error in code

Tags: php, json, curl

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init("URL");
    $username = "USERNAME";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $fields = array("from"=>array("name"=>"Bob","city"=>"SAINT-LAURENT","country"=>"CA","state"=>"QC","postal_code"=>"H4R1W4"),"to"=>array("is_commercial"=>true,"city"=>"ANJOU","country"=>"CA","state"=>"QC","postal_code"=>"H1J1Z4"),"packages"=>array("units"=>"imperial","type"=>"package","items"=>array("width"=>1,"height"=>2,"length"=>3,"weight"=>4)));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));        
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($data === FALSE) 
    { 
        $temp=curl_error($ch);
        echo "<p>cURL Error: {$temp}</p>";
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Error I got is

```
  {"error": "Unexpected input. Please make sure this is a valid JSON document"}
```

I'm unable to understand what this meant .
**After Update** the error i get is
Argument 1 passed to Support\ExposedObjectAbstract::setFromArray() must be of the type array, integer given, called in Shipping/Packages.php on line 22 and defined

Comment: it means you need to send json on this url. this is back response from server it will auth with valid json so you need to send a json on that

Comment: trying this json_encode($fields) is giving me some response error

Answer (score 1):

Your server end point (the URL you're calling) requires the input to be a valid JSON. In order to do this, you can replace:

```
$field_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

with:

```
$field_string = json_encode($fields);
```

Comment: Works but gives a new error  "Argument 1 passed to Support\ExposedObjectAbstract::setFromArray() must be of the type array"

Comment: This is the endpoint server side error. Consult the server owner.

Answer (score 1):

First set the HTTP header that you are sending `JSON`

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

And then, convert your array into `JSON`, and then setting to postfields

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
```

Comment: givces me the same error "Argument 1 passed to Support\ExposedObjectAbstract::setFromArray() must be of the type array"

Comment: @Harsha update your question with these suggestion. I mean update your code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Updated question accordingly

Comment: Your code is OK. Its the problem with your `JSON`. They array you are using is not the correct one I must say. Please see their API doc and adjust your array according to your one.

Answer (score 0):

$field_string = http_build_query($fields); is what the problem is , try to pass as array

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
```